# How to access element of vector<int*> using constant reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, syntax

I have some code try to use constant reference "tail" to access the last element of the vector:

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
printf("%d\n",v.back());
int& tail=v.back();
tail=2;
printf("%d\n",v.back());
```

which output is

```
1
2
```

now I want to have another code with similar function,but replace int to int*:

```
vector<int*> v;
v.push_back((int*)1);
printf("%p\n",v.back());
//remain part
```

and output should be

```
0x1
0x2
```

what is the syntax of the remain part?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to have a constant reference to the last item in your vector? Do you want to simply know why the output is different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what is the syntax of the remain part?

```
int*& tail=v.back();
tail = (int*)2;
```

or

```
v.back() = (int*)2
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `int*&`. `vector.back()` would return reference to `int` pointer.

```
vector<int*> v1;
v1.push_back((int*)1);
printf("%p\n",v1.back());
int*& tail1=v1.back();
tail1=(int*)2;
printf("%p\n",v1.back());
```

Outputs

```
0x1
0x2
```